# Merge rows in pandas with parent/child relationship

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example dataframe:

```
   case_number parent_case_number              name                role    paid                            notes
0  NYC-22-1234               None      Bob Cratchit          Accountant   50000   Scrooge's favorite accountant.
1  LON-22-1446               None  Ebenezer Scrooge             Partner  950000  Charles Dickens would be proud.
2  CHI-21-0115               None        Bob Marley  Partner (Deceased)  425000                        Shackled.
3  NYC-22-1235        NYC-22-1234      Bob Cratchit          Accountant   30000    One of Scrooge's accountants.
```

This can be constructed as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_data = [
    {
        "case_number": "NYC-22-1234",
        "parent_case_number": None,
        "name": "Bob Cratchit",
        "role": "Accountant",
        "paid": 50000,
        "notes": "Scrooge's favorite accountant.",
    },
    {
        "case_number": "LON-22-1446",
        "parent_case_number": None,
        "name": "Ebenezer Scrooge",
        "role": "Partner",
        "paid": 950000,
        "notes": "Charles Dickens would be proud.",
    },
    {
        "case_number": "CHI-21-0115",
        "parent_case_number": None,
        "name": "Bob Marley",
        "role": "Partner (Deceased)",
        "paid": 425000,
        "notes": "Shackled.",
    },
    {
        "case_number": "NYC-22-1235",
        "parent_case_number": "NYC-22-1234",
        "name": "Bob Cratchit",
        "role": "Accountant",
        "paid": 30000,
        "notes": "One of Scrooge's accountants.",
    },
]

df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
```

I want to merge children into their parents, where `parent_case_number` refers to a parent `case_number`.

- If a field is empty, it should take the value that is not empty (regardless of whether that value comes from child or parent).
- If a field has the same value in both rows, it should retain one of them.
- For conflicting values (e.g., `paid`), it should take the *highest* value.
- For `notes`, it should append the child to the parent's notes. In the event of conflicting values
- It should capture the `case_number` of the removed row(s) in a new column, `child_case_numbers`

In this example, the expected output is:

```
   case_number parent_case_number              name                role    paid                                                         notes child_case_numbers
0  NYC-22-1234               None      Bob Cratchit          Accountant   50000  Scrooge's favorite accountant. One of Scrooge's accountants.        NYC-22-1235
1  LON-22-1446               None  Ebenezer Scrooge             Partner  950000                               Charles Dickens would be proud.                NaN
2  CHI-21-0115               None        Bob Marley  Partner (Deceased)  425000                                                     Shackled.                NaN
```

I originally tried grouping but this assumes certain columns have identical values rather than a parent/child relationship.

I also thought about removing the child elements into a separate dataframe then merging back in on `case_number=`parent_case_number` but wasn't sure how to use the logic to impact specific fields for the merge.

I also thought perhaps an approach by data *type* could work also:

- Any

  - If parent or child has a value that is empty, use the populated value
- Strings:

  - If same, no change
  - If different, append child to parent
- Number (float64)

  - Use the biggest number (and a value is always "bigger" than NaN)

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Merge relevant subsets on case_number/parent_case_number
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[df["parent_case_number"].isna()].set_index("case_number"),
        df.dropna(subset="parent_case_number")
        .set_index("parent_case_number")
        .pipe(
            lambda df_: df_.rename(columns={col: f"child_{col}" for col in df_.columns})
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

# Set new values
new_df["paid"] = new_df[["paid", "child_paid"]].max(axis=1)
new_df["name"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: x["name"] or x["child_name"], axis=1)
new_df["role"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: x["role"] or x["child_role"], axis=1)
new_df["notes"] = new_df["notes"] + " " + new_df["child_notes"].fillna("")

# Cleanup
new_df = (
    new_df[
        [col for col in new_df.columns if not col.startswith("child_")]
        + ["child_case_number"]
    ]
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"index": "case_number"})
)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
   case_number parent_case_number              name                role  \
0  NYC-22-1234               None      Bob Cratchit          Accountant   
1  LON-22-1446               None  Ebenezer Scrooge             Partner   
2  CHI-21-0115               None        Bob Marley  Partner (Deceased)   

       paid                                                         notes  \
0   50000.0  Scrooge's favorite accountant. One of Scrooge's accountants.   
1  950000.0                              Charles Dickens would be proud.    
2  425000.0                                                    Shackled.    

  child_case_number  
0       NYC-22-1235  
1               NaN  
2               NaN
```