# Merge rows in pandas with parent/child relationships and potentially multiple children

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have data similar to this [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (written to facilitate easily recreating sample DataFrame, `df`):

```
d = [{'Case #': 'CHI22-01234',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Abraham Lincoln',
  'Demanded': 5000.0,
  'Paid': 2000.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'No',
  'C': 'Yes',
  'D': 'Yes',
  'Notes': 'Honest Abe with his stovepipe hat'},
 {'Case #': 'CHI22-01237',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Ebenezer Scrooge',
  'Demanded': 10000.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'No',
  'Notes': 'What a scrooge!'},
 {'Case #': 'NYC21-02222',
  'Parent Case #': 'CHI22-01237',
  'Name': 'Ebenezer Scrooge',
  'Demanded': 0.0,
  'Paid': 9500.0,
  'A': 'Unknown',
  'B': 'Unknown',
  'C': 'No',
  'D': 'Yes',
  'Notes': 'Scrooge has an apartment in NYC'},
 {'Case #': 'NYC22-03333',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Bob Marley',
  'Demanded': 1000000.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'No',
  'B': 'Unknown',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'He will send three ghosts'},
 {'Case #': 'PHX21-01234',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Bob Cratchit',
  'Demanded': 0.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'Unknown',
  'B': 'Unknown',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'Jr. accountant'},
 {'Case #': 'PHX21-01238',
  'Parent Case #': 'PHX21-01234',
  'Name': 'Bob Cratchit',
  'Demanded': 500000.0,
  'Paid': 22000.0,
  'A': 'No',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'No',
  'D': 'No',
  'Notes': 'Promoted to Sr. accountant 12/14/2021'},
 {'Case #': 'LAX22-12345',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Kim Kardashian',
  'Demanded': 50000.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'No',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'Kim & Kanye for president'},
 {'Case #': 'LAX22-12349',
  'Parent Case #': 'LAX22-12345',
  'Name': 'Kim Kardashian',
  'Demanded': 50000.0,
  'Paid': 30000.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'Updated data'},
 {'Case #': 'NYC23-21456',
  'Parent Case #': 'NYC22-03333',
  'Name': 'Bob Marley Mon',
  'Demanded': 0.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': nan},
 {'Case #': 'NYC23-21457',
  'Parent Case #': 'NYC22-03333',
  'Name': 'Bob Marley Jamaican Mon',
  'Demanded': 0.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'Unknown',
  'B': 'Unknown',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'Can it handle multiple children?'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I got this to work wherein each row has 0–1 child(ren). But once a row has 2 or more children, it breaks. I essentially followed [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588425/868044) but with some additional logic I've implemented, so that:

- Prefer values with data over empty values
- The A, B, C, D sample fields can have values `Yes`, `No`, or `Unknown`, and are preferred in that order whenever *any* of the rows (parent or child(ren)) has one of those values, which I've implemented in my `prefer_yes` function
- Use max value in `Demanded` and `Paid` columns
- Concatenate notes

My code works for merging rows with 0–1 child(ren) if you exclude the last row of the sample DataFrame.

```
def prefer_yes(parent, child):
    if parent == "Yes" or child == "Yes":
        return "Yes"
    elif parent == "No" or child == "No":
        return "No"

    return "Unknown"

# concat parent case number
mrg_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[df["Parent Case #"].isna()].set_index("Case #"),
        df.dropna(subset="Parent Case #")
        .set_index("Parent Case #")
        .pipe(lambda df_: df_.rename(columns={col: f"Child_{col}" for col in df_.columns})),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

# set new values
mrg_df["Demanded"] = mrg_df[["Demanded", "Child_Demanded"]].max(axis=1)
mrg_df["Paid"] = mrg_df[["Paid", "Child_Paid"]].max(axis=1)
mrg_df["A"] = mrg_df[["A", "Child_A"]].apply(lambda x: prefer_yes(x["A"], x["Child_A"]), axis=1)
mrg_df["B"] = mrg_df[["B", "Child_B"]].apply(lambda x: prefer_yes(x["B"], x["Child_B"]), axis=1)
mrg_df["C"] = mrg_df[["C", "Child_C"]].apply(lambda x: prefer_yes(x["C"], x["Child_C"]), axis=1)
mrg_df["D"] = mrg_df[["D", "Child_D"]].apply(lambda x: prefer_yes(x["D"], x["Child_D"]), axis=1)
mrg_df["Notes"] = mrg_df["Notes"] + "; " + mrg_df["Child_Notes"].fillna("")

# cleanup
mrg_df = (
    mrg_df[[col for col in mrg_df.columns if not col.startswith("Child_")] + ["Child_Case #"]]
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"index": "Case #"})
)
```

My question is how to adapt this to merge more than one child row so there is only one row per case number while applying this logic?

Expected output:

```
mrg_df.to_dict("records")

[{'Case #': 'CHI22-01234',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Abraham Lincoln',
  'Demanded': 5000.0,
  'Paid': 2000.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'No',
  'C': 'Yes',
  'D': 'Yes',
  'Notes': 'Honest Abe with his stovepipe hat; ',
  'Child_Case #': []},
 {'Case #': 'CHI22-01237',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Ebenezer Scrooge',
  'Demanded': 10000.0,
  'Paid': 9500.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'No',
  'D': 'Yes',
  'Notes': 'What a scrooge!; Scrooge has an apartment in NYC',
  'Child_Case #': ['NYC21-02222']},
 {'Case #': 'NYC22-03333',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Bob Marley',
  'Demanded': 1000000.0,
  'Paid': 0.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'He will send three ghosts; Can it handle multiple children?',
  'Child_Case #': ['NYC23-21456', 'NYC23-21457']},
 {'Case #': 'PHX21-01234',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Bob Cratchit',
  'Demanded': 500000.0,
  'Paid': 22000.0,
  'A': 'No',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'No',
  'D': 'No',
  'Notes': 'Jr. accountant; Promoted to Sr. accountant 12/14/2021',
  'Child_Case #': ['PHX21-01238']},
 {'Case #': 'LAX22-12345',
  'Parent Case #': nan,
  'Name': 'Kim Kardashian',
  'Demanded': 50000.0,
  'Paid': 30000.0,
  'A': 'Yes',
  'B': 'Yes',
  'C': 'Unknown',
  'D': 'Unknown',
  'Notes': 'Kim & Kanye for president; Updated data',
  'Child_Case #': ['LAX22-12349']}]
```

^^ Assumes child case numbers will be in a list but I am open to any method that works for that.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Thanks @Dan, do you always have maximum 1 level of parent? (can you have grand-parents, etc.?)

Comment: Yes max 1-level.

Comment: Have you had a chance to test the solution below?

Comment: Thanks @mozway I am just now sitting down to test and will let you know. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['Yes', 'No', 'Unknown'], ordered=True)
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(cat)

m = df['Parent Case #'].isna()
mrg_df = (df.loc[m, ['Case #', 'Parent Case #']]
 .merge(df[~m]
         .rename(columns={'Case #': 'Child Case #', 'Parent Case #': 'Case #'})
         .groupby('Case #').agg({'Child Case #': list, 'Name': ';'.join, 'Demanded': 'sum', 'Paid': 'sum',
                                 'A': 'min', 'B': 'min', 'C': 'min', 'D': 'min',
                                 'Notes': lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna())
                                }),
        on='Case #', how='left')
)
mrg_df[cols] = pd.concat([df.loc[m, cols], mrg_df[cols]]).groupby(level=0).min()

mrg_df['Notes'] = (df.loc[m, 'Notes'] + '; ' + mrg_df['Notes']).fillna(df.loc[m, 'Notes'])

mrg_df
```

Output:

```
        Case # Parent Case #                Child Case #  \
0  CHI22-01234           NaN                         NaN   
1  CHI22-01237           NaN               [NYC21-02222]   
2  NYC22-03333           NaN  [NYC23-21456, NYC23-21457]   
3  PHX21-01234           NaN               [PHX21-01238]   
4  LAX22-12345           NaN               [LAX22-12349]   

                                     Name  Demanded     Paid    A    B  \
0                                     NaN       NaN      NaN  Yes   No   
1                        Ebenezer Scrooge       0.0   9500.0  Yes  Yes   
2  Bob Marley Mon;Bob Marley Jamaican Mon       0.0      0.0  Yes  Yes   
3                            Bob Cratchit  500000.0  22000.0   No  Yes   
4                          Kim Kardashian   50000.0  30000.0  Yes  Yes   

         C        D                                              Notes  
0      Yes      Yes                  Honest Abe with his stovepipe hat  
1       No      Yes   What a scrooge!; Scrooge has an apartment in NYC  
2  Unknown  Unknown                                                NaN  
3       No       No  He will send three ghosts; Promoted to Sr. acc...  
4  Unknown  Unknown                       Jr. accountant; Updated data
```

---

**UPDATED Solution (slight tweak of proposed answer):**

```
cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=["Yes", "No", "Unknown"], ordered=True)
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(cat)

is_parent = df["Parent Case #"].isna()

df2 = df.copy()
df2['Merged Case #'] = df[['Parent Case #', 'Case #']].agg(lambda xs: xs.dropna()[0], axis=1)
df2['Parent Name'] = df.loc[is_parent, ['Name']]
df2 = df2 \
    .rename(columns={"Case #": "Child Case #"}) \
    .rename(columns={"Merged Case #": "Case #"}) \
    .groupby("Case #").agg(
    {
        "Child Case #": list,
        "Demanded": "max",
        "Paid": "max",
        "A": "min",
        "B": "min",
        "C": "min",
        "D": "min",
        "Notes": lambda x: '; '.join(x.dropna()),
        "Parent Name": lambda x: x.dropna(),
    }
)
```

Comment: So I do not want to concatenate the Name. I just want to use the parent case name and discard children names. I also do not want to sum the amounts. I only want to keep the max value from each. I am trying to figure out how to modify this accordingly. I think for those I can change sum to max. Experimenting....

Comment: This looks very helpful but I'm struggling to understand how it works and so how to tweak it. Thank you, though!

Comment: Use `max` in place of `sum`,  and replace `mrg_df['Name']` with `df.loc[m, 'Name']` after the merge. Give it a try and ping me tomorrow if you need help.

Comment: The notes concatenation is not working as intended, either. Even in your example it has some of the wrong ones (It concatenated Bob Marley and Bob Cratchit's notes in index 3 in the example in the answer, and the comment of a second child of Bob Marley, "Can it handle multiple children?" is nowhere to be found. I do appreciate the attempt, though and upvoted it. But unfortunately it does not solve this.

Comment: The A,B,C,D logic looks good, though!

Comment: I tweaked some and while the first child seems to work, the second child data are not being integrated properly (only one record, last record, in my MWE).

Comment: This got me very close (thank you)! Instead of separate df's, added a boolean whether `is_parent = df["Parent Case #"].isna()`. Copied the df into df2, `df2['Merged Case #'] = df[['Parent Case #', 'Case #']].agg(lambda xs: xs.dropna()[0], axis=1)` and got parent name via `df2['Parent Name'] = df.loc[is_parent, ['Name']]` then used your renames and groupby's from above (but no merge) and it worked! Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! So is the problem solved with those tweaks?

Comment: Yes those tweaks resolved it and maintained the correct parent values and such.

Comment: I would post the answer, but not sure how that works. Should I edit your answer? Post what worked for me as a new answer? Leave it be?

Comment: @Dan yes, you can suggest an edit to my answer if you want.

Comment: I added the solution that worked to bottom of answer and accepted answer. Your answer got me ~95% of the way there. Thanks!